# How do I troubleshoot this dd error when copying image to SD card?

Tags: sd-card, dd

I'm trying to follow the instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/179448/88802) on how to copy the Ubuntu image to an SD card for the Raspberry Pi.

I get the following error using the imagewriter application:

```
Trying to unmount /dev/mmcblk0p1...
/dev/mmcblk0p1 successfully unmounted
Executing: dd if=/media/ewilson/KINGSTON/2012-08-08-wheezy-armel.img of=/dev/mmcblk0
The dd process ended with an error!
```

I have no idea how to troubleshoot this. Any ideas?

Comment: Feel free to tag this question better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you root, or using sudo? you need to be, to write to a block device.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it was an issue related to not having administrative privileges. I did the same thing with `sudo imagewriter` and it worked.